# How to validate a product key of windows application in offline?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows, product-key

I have developed one windows application which has licensing to its users. I want to set validation for the product key in offline(Without internet connection).
For Example, during Windows operating system installation, the product key will be validated and used to activate the operating system. Such that i want some idea about how to do this concept.

Comment: Good luck with that!

Comment: I want many things too! Voting to close.

Comment: For Example, during Windows operating system installation, the product key will be validated and used to activate the operating system. Such that i want some idea about how to do this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a table or record of the product key and its license period.
Ask to user for entering the product key, match the entered key through coding, if it matches then only allow for installation.

Comment: Ok ! but if i make table then i want to connect internet to hit that database. now i want without internet how to validate

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11215354)

Comment: @ChrisStillwell This most definitely *is* an answer, please pay more attention.

Comment: You can also make a record as a class with the field productkey and more. @Sabari